# How to call non-static method from static?

Tags: java

I tried to call non-static `drawScore()` method from static `calldrawScore()`, but I got the error `"cannot find symbol constructor Game"` on line `Game draw = new Game();` in `calldrawScore()`. When I pass with mouse over that line it says `"GameScreen (Game) in Game cannot be applied to ()"`.

Comment: To call a non-static method you need an instance of the class the method expect.  If you have this, you can call it anywhere.

Comment: Remember in OOP static means its a Class method as no-static means its an Instance method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Answer (score 2):

**-** Its rule of thumb that a **static method can't access any non-static variable or methods**.

**-** It is because `static member` belongs to the `class` where as `non-static` members belongs to the `object`, so as the static member tries to access a non-static member it won't be clear that which objects member is being accessed, so its prohibited in JAVA.

Comment: You can access a non static method from static method by creating an instance in the static method.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic you are right about it, thats one way of defining a singleton principle, but as far as i know, there is no direct way of accessing a non-static member from a static member and was something i wanted the OP to know, but thanks for providing another angle to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can change "getScore(int x)" into:

```
public static int getScore(int x, GameScreen gs) {
        score = x;
        gs.drawScore();
        return score;
    }
```

and now you can call it in "GameScree" by

```
GameScreen.getScore(valueSome, yourObject);
```

Another way is to change all GameScreen into [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585720/how-to-use-the-singleton-pattern-in-an-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

Your class GameScreen constructor is taking Game class object as a parameter. You can either get the current Game instance and pass it as a argument or create a default constructor in your Gamescreen class.

Answer (score 0):

To do `GameScreen d = new GameScreen()` you need to have 0-argument constructor for `GameScreen`. You don't have such constructor.

Anyway, your code looks preety bad, because you are creating new `GameScreen` in every `calldrawScore()`...

I think you need to read what's the difference between static and non-static methods. Then go back, design it  and implement better.