# Switch between two activities and keep music playing

Tags: android, object, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

Here is what I want to achieve in my app: I have 3 menus in the startup page: PLAY , INSTRUCTIONS , HIGH SCORE.
I have theme music playing in the background with the help of MediaPlayer object. I just want that the theme music should be playing for the PLAY and INSTRUCTIONS menu, uninterrupted, i.e, if the activity changes from MAIN MENU to INSTRUCTIONS and vice-versa , the music should be playing uninterrupted. But the music should stop as soon as the PLAY activity is started. I don't know the best way to do it, but all I can think of is sending the MediaPlayer object that started the theme music to PLAY's oncreate and stop it there. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi, its better to use Singleton for mediaplayer and that way you get access to this class from every activity. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585720/how-to-use-the-singleton-pattern-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a Service to play the music (and to do so off of the main thread). Here are relevant pages on

[Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

[Media playback](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: If I start my service in Main Menu activity , I will need to stop that service in Play activity, so , I will need the service object declared and initialized in Main Menu in the Play activity. Same problem again. Or is there another way?

Comment: You don't declare and initialize instances of Services, just like you don't do that for Activities (and other application components). Android does that for you. Just use the `startService` and `stopService` methods in your activities. If the service is already started, then the next startService is directed to the already running service.

Comment: Thank you, It looks satisfactory , I think I need to read those pages before I can comment anything further.