# How to get switch button status and pass to another activity using shared preferences

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am having switch button in one activity and another switch button in another activity.In my application i want to get the status of switch button weather it was on on or off state,I want to pass the status of switch button to the another activity using shared preferences and set the switch button state which was present in the second activity according to the first switch button state.
can any one tell me how to do this please.Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585720/how-to-use-the-singleton-pattern-in-an-android-project) and create methods for setting and getting state of your toggle button. Later you can access the state of the toggle button from anywhere.
You can also use  [shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for this.
**Set State:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.ali.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("state", yourButton1.isChecked());
editor.apply();
```

**Get State:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.ali.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean state= prefs.getBoolean("state", false);
yourButton2.setChecked(state);
```

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception dude at boolean state= prefs.getBoolean("state", null);  @Ali Hassan

Comment: apply my edited answer. you won't get the exception now.