# How to write a database for an android app

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

In my app I need a database with different tables that I would write before and then just read in the app. I know how to create a new database, write and read it in the app using SQL but I actually don't know with what program (and in which format) I can write the database before adding it in the assets folder.

Would anyone help me with that, please?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ It run on Mac OS , Windows and Linux

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), which is an on-device SQL implementation.  Be aware that this will only support a subset of SQL operations found in most traditional relational DBs. If you need full SQL support you'll have to write back-end web services hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for creating your database.

Here is my example to create simple database that have store City with 2 filed is City_ID and City_Name:

```
public class DiLiBusDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DiLiBusDB";
private static final String TBL_CITY = "City";
private static final String CITY_ID_FIELD = "City_ID";
private static final String CITY_NAME_FIEDL = "City_Name";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DiLiBusDatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
Context context;
//synchronized to make sure have only one thread is run at the same time
public static DiLiBusDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new DiLiBusDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private DiLiBusDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    this.context = context;
    this.database = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE"+" "+TBL_CITY+"("+CITY_ID_FIELD+" "+"TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"+CITY_NAME_FIEDL+" "+"TEXT"+");";
    String queryIndex = "CREATE INDEX city_name_idx ON"+ " "+TBL_CITY +"("+CITY_NAME_FIEDL+");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(queryIndex);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}
p/s: I using [Singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585720/how-to-use-the-singleton-pattern-in-an-android-project) to create my database. Moreover, if you want to save your db in SDCard, u can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373863/how-to-store-sqlite-database-directly-on-sdcard)

Comment: I'm sorry I it's not what I was searching for: I need to have in my app a database already created before outside the application. Thank you, anyway

Comment: 1. Do you want to make a server that save your database and your application connect with server to get data ?
Or  Do you want to create SQLite outside application then embed it to your app for using?

Comment: I just want to create some tables that the users can only read from inside the application

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries for database:

- [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)
- [Active Android](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started)
- [Green DAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/)

This is the simplest way for creating database because you operates on your defined data models.